# Вывод элементов списка в строку C++

Tags: c++, строки, список, вывод

Вот код:

```
result = current->fio + "\t" + current->depart + "\t" + current->exp +
            + "\t" + current->pos + "\t" + current->start;
```

Но result выводится без \t.

Comment: "Но result выводится без \t." - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: "\t" это управляющий символ. когда вы пытаетесь выводить, этот символ просто формотирует вывод. Его  не будет в строке  в виде \t

Comment: @Igor выводил в ListBox

Comment: @ARHovsepyan спасибо, вы помогли решить проблему

Comment: это самое главное